# Apache2 mixing forward and reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy, forwarding

I upgraded apache2, which behaves different now.
I want to mix a forward proxy, only accessable from the intranet and a reverse proxy which should be accessable from the internet.

What happens is that with my configuration the forward proxy was accessable from the internet. I moved the forwarding proxy to a new virtual host. So I tried to setup the proxy to block everything and only setup the proxy for the reverse hosts. However the forward proxy is still available, but i am unable to connect to the reverse proxy address:
"You don't have permission to access /s/ on this server."

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
           SSLProxyEngine on

     ProxyRequests On

    <Proxy *>
            Deny from all
   </Proxy>
    <Proxy /s/>
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

   ProxyPass /s/ http://internalwebserver/
   ProxyPassReverse /s/ http://internalwebserver/
</VirtualHost>
```

How do I have to setup apache ?
Is it possible to setup the forward and reverse proxy in one virtualhost ?

Thanks in advance
Simon

Comment: Just don't. While it's *technically* possible, there's a lot of risk here that at somepoint in the future you will find yourself running an open proxy being exploited left, right and centre. Run a seperate server for both.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question,
ProxyRequest On was the culprit. This is only needed for a forward proxy. Also having this setting enabled, enables all requests for the "normal" webserver to be proxied.

When having a reverse and forward proxies, a separate VirtualHost on another port is needed for the forward proxy (ProxyRequest on), leaving the reverse proxies in the normal VirtualHost with ProxyRequest off, so that also no proxying is done for the webserver.

Comment: Is it required that the other vhost is on another port?

Answer (score 0):

Your `/s/` proxy has `Deny from all` directive.

Try to limit allowed list to the proxy you want your LAN to have access to with:

`Allow from 192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12 10.0.0.0/8`

And deny from all others.

Comment: Sorry, but my question has been misunderstood.
I want access to /s/ from the internet but disable the proxying from the internet (I can setup the local proxy on another virtual address).
I thought specifying the following:
     <Proxy *>
            Deny from all
   </Proxy>
    <Proxy /s/>
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
but this disables everything.
How can I overrule the /s/ behaviour. Is it valid to have two <Proxy> blocks ?